# style trigger setting colour to cells with specific value in data grid

Tags: xml, wpf, datagrid, cell

I am trying to set colour to a cell of a data grid with the help of trigger, but the following code is not working

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="Content" Value="1">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGren"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

if the content of a datagrid cell is 1 I want that cell to be coloured yellow pleses help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change datagrid cell background on some constant value then you can try something like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="YourColumnHeader" Binding="{Binding SomeValue}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="{Binding SomeBool, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToBrushConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Converter code will be something like this:

```
public class BoolToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isDiffer = (bool)value;
        if (isDiffer)
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        else
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.